# Can't get jQuery working on pages other than index

Tags: jquery, view, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a application using .Net Core 2.2.

It's a MVC app and I want to get some simple jQuery working.

I'm using a layout page and can get the JS working on the index.cshtm but when I click redirect to another page from there JS doesn't work. Looking at the developer tools in Chrome I get a resource not found 404

I've tried a few things I found on Stack Overflow like positioning and using @Scripts.Render etc. but so far no luck.

_Layout.cshtml

```
[<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="css/*" asp-href-exclude="css/all.min.css">
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="css/all.min.css" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img asp-append-version="true" alt="Logo" src="~/img/recipelogo.png" style="max-width:100%" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 titlecol">
                <span class="title">@ViewBag.Title</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
                @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>][1]
```

And the View here:

```
@using System.Collections.Specialized
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V3.Pages.Internal
@using Shared.Models
@model RecipeModel

<form asp-action="Add">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <label asp-for="Category"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Category" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <label asp-for="Serves"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Serves" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <label asp-for="Ingredients"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @*<table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Units</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Ingredients){
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                    <td>@item.QuantityUnits</td>

                </tr>
                }
            </table>*@


            <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
            <p>Click me away!</p>
            <p>Click me too!</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@section scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("p").click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Where you called this layout? just add this in view

Answer (score 0):

One you installed the nugger package, you have to reference it.
You can add

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

In every page you want to use the jquery, or go to your `_Layour.cshtml` and add the line above into the `enviroment include="Development"` tag, so it 's accesible from every page

Comment: Thanks Raul. I used NPN to install & bundled js & css in wwwroot. I had tried adding  to _Layout.cshtml and tried again but still no joy. Can see the code and reference in the rendered page html (see image attached) but doesn't seem to reference. The jquery actually works in the main index page fine - it's just the child pages. Cheers Rob   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUVEN.png

Comment: Ok, I can see your problem is that you do not have the folder referenced correctly. Make sure the route is correct, it should be inside wwwroot./lib/ etc. I reccomend you to drag the file into your code, and it will create the link directly, thisis an image of how should it be [link](http://prntscr.com/p2j8aw) Also, what you can do is use the cdn link, `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks again for the patience. I tried referencing as suggested and pasted files into a lib folder in wwwroot [https://prnt.sc/p2lil5] and then made sure was in _Layout [https://prnt.sc/p2lkoa] and the code is in the view. [https://prnt.sc/p2lmz6] but still not working.

Comment: You must reference a file, not a folder. find the file which ends in .js [like this](http://prntscr.com/p2luqo)

Comment: Yes - I had done that [https://prnt.sc/p2lkoa] in _Layout.cshtm and [https://prnt.sc/p2xnyq] is the jquery.js file in wwwroot. I'm still puzzled as to why the jquery works fine in the index view but not in children view's from that index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following format. I hope it will work fine.

_Layout.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="css/*" asp-href-exclude="css/all.min.css">
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="css/all.min.css" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img asp-append-version="true" alt="Logo" src="~/img/recipelogo.png" style="max-width:100%" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 titlecol">
                <span class="title">@ViewBag.Title</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha256-E/V4cWE4qvAeO5MOhjtGtqDzPndRO1LBk8lJ/PR7CA4=">
        </script>
    </environment>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

A content page like this:

```html
@using System.Collections.Specialized
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V3.Pages.Internal
@using Shared.Models
@model RecipeModel

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<form asp-action="Add">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <label asp-for="Category"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Category" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <label asp-for="Serves"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Serves" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <label asp-for="Ingredients"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @*<table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Units</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Ingredients){
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                    <td>@item.QuantityUnits</td>

                </tr>
                }
            </table>*@


            <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
            <p>Click me away!</p>
            <p>Click me too!</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
<script>
 $(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'p', function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Moving OP's solution from the question to an answer.</sub>

> Got this working by adding the following to [bundleconfig.json file](https://prnt.sc/p2xx8u) which created [jquery.js](https://prnt.sc/p2xwpq) in the wwwroot folder and then added [reference and scripts section](https://prnt.sc/p2xxym) to _Layout.cshmtl. Finally added the scripts section to the bottom of the [view](https://prnt.sc/p2xycn).